# Microsoft Teams response to message extension with open url action

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to be able to open url with message extension in Teams. Is it possible?

What I can do so far is to response the message extension with an adaptive card which has a openurl action button then from the adaptive card, the user can click on the button and open the url. This way they user has to click twice to just open an url with message extension.

[Example code added]

Response to "composeExtension/fetchTask" bot activity with adaptive card wrapped in attachment in the task info.

```
final Attachment attachment = new Attachment().withContentType("application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive").withContent(
    cardBuilder.createAdaptiveCard());
final TaskInfo taskInfo = TaskInfo.builder()
    .title("Message extension using adaptive card")
    .card(attachment)
    .height(TaskModuleDimension.SMALL)
    .width(TaskModuleDimension.SMALL)
    .build();

return new BotActivityResponse(TaskType.CONTINUE, taskInfo);
```

Note: I am able to return just a TaskInfo with an url which opens a popup. However, what I want is to open url in a browser out of Teams app.

Comment: A few questions: Is this adaptive card coming from a bot? Which messaging extension feature are you trying to use? Task module? Can you please post your code showing what you have tried?

Comment: @StevenKanberg I added the sample code and also a note.

Comment: You need to send a card to use open URL action in Message Extension. Currently there is no other way to do a openUrl on one click.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thank you for your information. That's what I need to know.